# Is the DOM ready when a script is executed within the body tree?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, domready

I have a snipped that is placed inside ANY website, in the middle of the document like in the middle of an article, not inside `<head>`. This script loads an external script on my domain by appending a `<script>` tag (pretty much like google analytics snippet does).

My questions is if that script is placed inside the body, does the DOM hasn't already been parsed, so I can safely assume that I can manipulate the DOM when my script is evaluated without waiting for DOMReady event?

I'm asking because theres a big delay when my script start executing and when the DOMReady event fires (see the brown bar). I'm using this [DOMReady implementation](http://beeker.io/jquery-document-ready-equivalent-vanilla-javascript)

[image]

The **Host Website**

```html
<html>

<head>
  ...
</head>

<body>
  Website content
  ...
  <div>
    
  <!-- Snippet -->
  <div id="myContainer"></div> <!------(I should be able to query this div) -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script');
      ga.type = 'text/javascript';
      ga.async = true;
      ga.src = 'http://example.com/script.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
  </script>
  <!-- Snippet End -->
  
  <div>
  More content
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

The *example.com/* **script.js**

```
(function(){
    //by this time div#myContainer should exist, right?
    var div = document.getElementById('myContainer');
    div.innerHTML = "Hello World!";
})();
```

Some considerations:

- I don't have control over the Host page, it can have anything inside it.
- Support for old browsers are a concern.
- I should be able to append stuff as soon as possible, I can't wait for things like other libraries, and images to finish loading.
- It should reliable work everytime.

Comment: All elements before your first script element will exist already.

Comment: The only possible issue I can see is if your script loads before heavy media assets like video or big images are loaded. But if you're not after media data this should not be a concern. And still if you're targetting a known selector, you can still attach `onload` listeners to those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's right. If you have a script tag at the bottom of the body, then by the time your script runs, everything is rendered before that.

W3Schools have a nice article on this subject.

Scripts in `<head>`

> > Scripts to be executed when they are called, or when an event is triggered, are placed in functions.
> >     Put your functions in the head section, this way they are all in one place, and they do not interfere with page content.

Scripts in `<body>`

> > If you don't want your script to be placed inside a function, or if your script should write page content, it should be placed in the body section.